# THREE js remove whole scene

Tags: three.js

I have few scenes with cameras in one page.

One of them is a map view.

I can simply load this scene by function, but **is in THREE js simple way to remove whole scene?**

When I do not showing map, I don't want to keep objects loaded and rendered for better performance.

I found only how to remove child by child in loop. But I hope there is a better solution.

Comment: removing the children in a loop is what you should do.

Answer (score 1):

Just removing THREE objects from your scene is not enough to delete them from memory.  You have to call the dispose() methods on the objects' geometries, materials and textures.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5175

After you call your dispose and remove methods, do a diagnostic like this (where this.renderer is your THREE.Renderer):

```
if (this.renderer && (this.renderer.info.memory.geometries || this.renderer.info.memory.programs || this.renderer.info.memory.textures)) {
        loge("VIEW.clear: geometries=" + this.renderer.info.memory.geometries + " programs=" + this.renderer.info.memory.programs + " textures=" + this.renderer.info.memory.textures);
    }
```

If the number of programs, geometries and textures isn't stable, you are inviting performance issues and a memory leak.